# Saving HTML to MySQL via MVC post

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

At the moment I have a simple method that will post a string to my MySQL server and it will save the text without a problem, but If i place a   tag inside of the string, it comes up in my google console the page could not be found and I get this post error

```
send jquery-1.8.2.js:8430
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.2.js:7982
(anonymous function) jSnapTabs.js:93
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.2.js:3077
elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery-1.8.2.js:2695
jQuery.event.trigger jquery-1.8.2.js:2960
(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.2.js:3618
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.8.2.js:625
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.8.2.js:255
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger jquery-1.8.2.js:3617
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.2.js:3671
$.tabs.select jSnapTabs.js:64
$.Widget._trigger jquery-ui-1.8.24.js:607
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.24.js:10988
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.2.js:3077
elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery-1.8.2.js:2695
```

Anyone have any ideas on why it doesn't save?

Comment: I don't anything useful here that would help figure it out, but I wonder if you encoded the string properly before sending.  Where's the SQL?

Comment: how would I change the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

My MVC model was this originally.

```
public class StockItemDescriptionModel : Entity
{
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You just have to add a simple Attribute to it

```
public class StockItemDescriptionModel : Entity
{
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now ASP.NET allows this model to pass in HTML on field Description,
Hope this helps other people